# How to say "dulcet" in verbal English (or slang)?

Tags: adjectives, slang, formality, conversation

For example, if somebody sitting next to me hummed or sang a song and I want to tell him that his song is dulcet, in a polite but informal manner (or even slang). How can I express that?

Should I just simply say "it sounds good" or "it sounds nice"? Or there are some better ways to say it?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your purpose for saying it?

Comment: Hi, it is just an example. I want to know how to say "dulcet" in an informal/verbal way.

Comment: The word "dulcet" is often paired with "tones" e.g. "the dulcet tones of your favourite easy listening tunes"

Comment: Also, 'dulcet' is relatively rare. It's not naturally used even in formal speech or writing. It's a bit of a cliche for purple prose or poetry.

Comment: What are you asking for that's not provide simply by the dictionary definition of "dulcet"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For slang do not use "sweet" safest bet is

> That's a nice melody.

Just be sure there is no partner the other side who may be called Melody.

Alternatively as long as they are not South African you could say

> That's a nice tuuunnee

In fact why not just simply say

> **That's a nice song.**

Comment: “Melodic ditty” does not sound like something a native speaker of English would be likely to say, and it’s certainly not slang (quite the opposite – it would be considered rather high in register).

Answer (score 0):

You can use "sweet."

> What a sweet song!
>
> That sounds so sweet.

Comment: Are you commenting on the song or the singing?